# Making a dynamically generated list mutually exclusive

Tags: jquery, django

I have an unordered list that appears as part of an autocomplete dropdown and that is being dynamically generated, by a [plugin](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light), that only appears in the DOM after a user interaction. On the page in question, this list can be rendered multiple times. I want to make the list mutually exclusive so that when one item is selected, it can no longer be selected in a new list. The main problem I am having is that I am struggling to get access to the element that I actually need to perform the event on. The code that is generated for the list is like so:

```
<span class="select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--open" style="position: absolute; top: 310px; left: 523.172px;">
    <span class="select2-dropdown select2-dropdown--below" dir="ltr" style="width: 144px;">
        <span class="select2-search select2-search--dropdown">
            <input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox">
        </span>
        <span class="select2-results">
            <ul class="select2-results__options" role="tree" id="select2-id_eventconfigstepkeycharacteristicfield_set-0-key_characteristic-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
                <li class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true">Depot</li>
                <li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Month</li>
                <li class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">bdfdf</li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

I basically want to make so that when a `li` has `select2-results__option--highlighted` in its class it will be removed from the list when it is rendered again. So far I can get access to this by adding a `jQuery` event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.select2-container.select2-container--default.select2-container--open', function () {
    console.log('working');
});
```

and this is working but I have been unable to get the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set up your click handler to de-select all others:

```
$(document).on('click', '.select2-container.select2-container--default.select2-container--open li', function () {
    $('.select2-results__option--highlighted').removeClass('select2-results__option--highlighted');
    $(this).addClass('select2-results__option--highlighted');
});
```

You may even be able to simplify it:

```
$(document).on('click', '.select2-container li', function () {
    $('.select2-results__option--highlighted').removeClass('select2-results__option--highlighted');
    $(this).addClass('select2-results__option--highlighted');
});
```

And, if you want to completely hide all the others:

```
$(document).on('click', '.select2-container li', function () {
    $('.select2-results__option--highlighted').setStyle('display', 'none');
    $(this).setStyle('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: I'm looking to remove the list item from the list if it is highlighted so that it won't appear in the list if a new dropdown is selected but will still appear highlighted in the dropdown where it was selected.

Comment: Oh I see. Check out my updated answer. That should at least get you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had to adapt it a little but this definitely got me going in the right direction

Comment: Awesome. Great to hear.